# Get and show AJAX response while AJAX is working yet

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm using AJAX through the code below:

**Javascript :**

```
function CallAJAX() {
    var url = "MyAJAX.ashx";
    xmlRequest.open("POST", url);
    xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = function () { ApplyUpdateCallAJAX() }
    xmlRequest.send(null);
}

function ApplyUpdateCallAJAX() {
    if (xmlRequest.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlRequest.status == 200) {
            var response = xmlRequest.responseText;
            document.getElementById("resultDIV").innerHTML = response;
        }
    }
}
```

**.ashx file (in asp.net) :**

```
...
...
HttpResponse response = context.Response;
response.ContentType = "text/html";
...

response.Write("Connecting...");
// connecting to database - for example takes 10 seconds !

...
response.Write("Reading...");
// reading data from database - for example takes 5 seconds !

...
```

This way user will wait 15 seconds for AJAX and then see the result like this:

```
Connecting...Reading...
```

Is there anyway to show the two responses independently !?

For example some way that we have the result described below:

User first see the text **Connecting...** and then after 10 seconds (the time that connecting longs!) the text changes and user see the text **Reading...** ?

Comment: It's not possible to do with XHR

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do you know what should I use to get such result? and how ?

Comment: Probably [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets)

Comment: Well, you could try a workaround: After writing "Connecting...", flush the stream (i.e. send that part of the response to the client). The xmlRequest.readyState should then change to 3 (LOADING). Once the connection finishes, "Reading..." is sent and the request completes (readyState is set to 4).